# CentOS Apache virtual hosts sites-available type structure

Tags: centos, apache-httpd, apache-virtualhost

I just set up LAMP on a new CentOS server.
Previously when I installed LAMP on Ubuntu, I always needed to create a virtual host definition for each website I create in my `/var/www` directory.

But on CentOS, I realised once I put my website into my `/var/www` directory, it's immediately visible on my browser.

I included this directive: `Include conf/vhosts/*.conf` in my `httpd.conf` file in order to define virtual hosts for specific sites.
Inside my vhost directory, I have defined my `*.conf` files.

Can anyone tell me what needs to be edited, possibly in `httpd.conf`, to stop sites that don't have an individual `/vhosts/*.conf` file from displaying when visited?

Below is my default virtual host definition information which I amend for each new site:

```
<VirtualHost var/www/aSite:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
    DocumentRoot var/www/aSite
    ServerName myServer
    ErrorLog var/www/aSite/logs/error_log
    CustomLog var/www/aSite/logs/access_log common
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: You know that `<VirtualHost var/www/aSite:80>` doesn't make any sense, right?  The argument before the port number (`:80`) is supposed to be a hostname or ip address (or `*`).

Comment: :-) yes! I just put aSite in there as a place holder

Answer (score 1):

I'll tell from my mind and memory (can't verify on CentOS), you have somewhere in httpd.conf

- Loaded `mod_vhost_alias` [Apache Module mod_vhost_alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_vhost_alias.html)

> This module creates dynamically configured virtual hosts, by allowing
>   the IP address and/or the Host: header of the HTTP request to be used
>   as part of the pathname to determine what files to serve. This allows
>   for easy use of a huge number of virtual hosts with similar
>   configurations.

- `VirtualDocumentRoot` defined into /var/www/(something) + possible `VirtualScriptAlias`

PS: Can you tell me, why you want to stop this (nice, from my POV) behavior?

Answer (score 0):

I recently setup a centos 7 web-server with virtual hosts and I added a `<VirtualHost>` directive for a blank webpage or coming soon page. This `<VirtualHost>` directive needs to be above `Include conf/vhosts/*.conf` in the httpd.conf file.