# Remove a directory level from a website URL

Tags: apache-httpd, hostname

Can anyone tell me how to configure apache to not display a website folder name at the end of a base URL, please? - but only for one out of many websites.

Let me describe the scenario ...

I have a test server with a number of websites in separate folders inside `/var/www`.
Because it a test server, I am accessing it via it's IP address (64.244.144.78). 
So I would access a website via `64.244.144.78/a_website_folder`

The trouble began when I needed one of the sites, which is called `applications`, to have a sub-domain name of `applications.ourorganisation.org` instead of using the IP Address format as above.

The sub-domain was created by our IT guy on our currently existing Windows server. He then pointed the sub-domain at my Linux test server's IP address of 64.244.144.78 (apparently he could not add the subdirectory information leading to the applications website).

To counter this problem, I created an `index.php` file in `64.244.144.78/var/www` and used PHP code to redirect to the applications website folder.

All that worked but I now when I visit `applications.ourorganisation.org`, I am redirected to `applications.ourcompany.org/applications`.

It not a disaster but I would like to NOT have the `applications` directory name at the end.

Comment: Why aren't you using named virtual hosts in apache?

Answer (score 5):

What you need is [VirtualHost](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/examples.html) definition.

In you `/etc/httpd/conf.d` (Fedora) create a new file and call it `application.ourorganisation.org.conf`.

**In this file try this format:**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName application.ourorganisation.org
    ServerAdmin admin@ourorganisation.org
    DocumentRoot /var/www/a_website_folder/

    <Location />
        Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks
    </Location>

</VirtualHost>
```

**Then restart httpd:**

> service httpd restart

If you want other hostname to be also forwarded to the same config, Try this under the `ServerName` Directive

```
ServerAlias app.ourorganisation.org application.localhost
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have virtualhosts defined on my server under **/etc/httpd/conf/vhosts**.The only problem is they don't have any effect. When I build sites on my Ubuntu VPS, I always have to define a virtualhost file for each site, enable it and restart apache for the site to be visible and work. BUT, on my employers CENTOS server, I noticed, totally be accident, once I drop my wedsite files into **/var/www**, it immediately becomes visible in a browser. I described this issue @ http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/35319/centos-apache-virtual-hosts-sites-available-type-structure

Comment: Oh you can change the default httpd.conf `DocumentRoot` to be something like `var/www/goaway/` which bypass your `application` folder. Might not be the most elegant solution but it should work

Comment: yep! I already changed **DocumentRoot** but remember I have multiple websites on the server. I can only make this URL renaming work for one site. HOWEVER, I do think finding a way to make my **virtualhost** definitions to work will solve this problem ...

Comment: Im not sure what you are after, but you can create multiple virtual hosts directive for multiple site.